# Which one is faster for obtaining substring of a given string in C++? The string constructor or the substr() function?

Tags: c++, string

Whenever i need to obtain a substring of a given string, I've always had a dilemma over which method would be faster.

**Method 1** - using std::string::string (const string& str, size_t pos, size_t len = npos) - the string constructor

`string str = "abcdefgf";` 
`string sub(str, 2, 4);        //sub = "cdef"`

**Method 2** - using std::string::substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) - substr() function of string class

`string str = "abcdefgf";` 
`string sub = str.substr(2,4)  //sub = "cdef"`

Comment: Did you measure? I'd suspect there won't be a notable difference.

Comment: I believe they are pretty equal in terms of performance but the latter seems to be more clear that you want to get a sub-string.

Comment: Only way to find out is likely to measure it. Make a couple million strings, chop them up them all one way and then the other, time them and see what happens. Bet they're both slower than a [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view).

Comment: You're worrying about the wrong thing.

Comment: I doubt there is much difference. I'd even expect that one of them calls the other or both call the same underlying function. You could use views or iterators to pass a sub range without copying anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::string owns its data, so with either API the cost is dominated by allocating and copying data for the substring. What you may want is [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view), which avoids all this by "viewing" the underlying data without copying.